# Why NamedScopes invoke dispose methods from finalizer?

Tags: c#, ninject, named-scope

I noticed that when I use `IDisposable` objects inside Ninject named scope my `Dispose` method is called from finalizer. But my object or some of it references may be already finalized at that point.

Am I missing something? Is it a correct behavior or a bug?

Stacktrace:

```
в NInjectNamedScopes.User.ChatService.Dispose()
в Ninject.Activation.Strategies.DisposableStrategy.<Deactivate>b__0(IDisposable x)
в Ninject.Activation.InstanceReference.IfInstanceIs[T](Action`1 action)
в Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Deactivate>b__4(IActivationStrategy s)
в Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
в Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(CacheEntry entry)
в Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(IEnumerable`1 cacheEntries)
в Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Clear(Object scope)
в Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope.DisposeNotifyingObject.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
в Ninject.Infrastructure.Disposal.DisposableObject.Finalize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In general it's a very bad practice to access other managed objects from finalizer.
2. I found few other performance-related problems in the source code of `NamedScopes` extensions.

So yes, this is a mistake and I recommend everyone to *not use NamedScopes extension at all* until it's fixed. Personally I've made some performance tests and chosen another IoC container, AutoFac, which works by an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since ninject still has a reference to your `IDisposable`, it shouldn't be possible that your `IDisposable` has already been finalized. But it seems strange that in your case the `Dispose` method is called from the finalizer. Can you provide a stacktrace?

### Named-Scope Behavior

By default with `InNamedScope`, ninject keeps a `WeekReference` to `DefinesNamedScope` (root) and periodically checks whether it's still alive. Once it has been detected as garbage collected, the `InNamedScope`-objects of that scope are disposed (Ninject keeps a strong reference to these).

To make sure the `InNamedScope`-d objects are disposed right away after the scope-root object, add `INotifyWhenDisposed` to the scope-root.

Comment: Stacktrace added. It looks like `DisposeNotifyingObject` ignores `disposing` argument.

Comment: yes you're right [it does ignore the `disposing` argument](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/blob/c8d8e4b99a1add1fc11f455034343606f1538b50/src/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/DisposeNotifyingObject.cs). But as stated in my answer, you should still be able to implement `INotifyWhenDisposed` in your root-object to improve the disposal process.